# Can't get dictionary item by index - cannot subscript String with an Int

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a dictionary where key is string and value is array of strings.

```
var someItems : [String: [String]] = [String: [String]]()
```

I am trying to get item by it's index...

```
var temp = someItems[0]
```

But I am gettings error:

```
'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work?

Comment: Because you have a dictionary with `String` keys… why would you even expect this to work?

Comment: var temp = someItems["String"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary` is `key` based not `index` based and the key is declared as `String`

```
var temp = someItems["key"]
```

Comment: What structure can I use to have [String:Array] and to be able to get item by index?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. There are third-party solutions like OrderedDictionary (http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/) which use a backing array for the keys

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary items are not sorted and therefore you can't call them with index. You should be able to access its value by writing someItems ["theString"], where theString is the selected key.

Answer (score 0):

try this

if let array = someItems["your key for array"] as NSArray{

```
  print(array)
```

}

it will return your array for the entered key